# multiple class styles in separate css references

Tags: html, css, mobile, html-email

Start this off with I'm interpreting someone else's coding and this is email coding.

Within the following code, table cell is referencing `.full` and the image code is referencing `.imageblock` and `.icon`, as well as there is a specific `.full` img style in my CSS. My question is that each style has something slightly different, so how do I know which one to edit. Also, in the CSS there are two `.icon` references. Why are these separated and not together?

Here is the coding:

```css
.full {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  !important
}

.full img {
  display: block;
  !important;
  width: 30% !important;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
}

.imageBlock {
  display: block !important;
  height: auto !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}

.icon {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
}

.icon {
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<td width="25%" dir="ltr" class="full">
  <img src="https://okcu-uga.edu.185r.net/graphics/okcu-uga/JSF201920/email/icon-badge.gif" width="100" height="100" class="imageBlock icon" />
</td>
```

Comment: *Edited the imageBlock tag

Answer (score 0):

Edit `.imageblock` since the person has forced the properties to that selector. [Here is more info about CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

and there are two `.icon` rules because the previous dev had no idea what he was doing :p, remove the second one.

Comment: with a minute of testing, you can see that b is lowercase in imageblock, and uppercase in the html, so the forced propreties are to me just a lot of debug, beacause "I can't get this css bit to work"

Comment: I updated the original question. The lowercase 'b' was an error in my typing, but the duplicate .icon was not. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

why are they two .icon with the same rule ? maybe the coder could'nt find the second one and wrote the first, setting inportant in order to bypass the second ?

then in order to know the order, there is the magic way of opening it with a dev tool, if  inspect the img with chrome, i can see the the following order :

```
.full img {
  display: block;
  width: 30% !important;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
}
.icon {
  overwritten by important rule below---padding-left: 25px;
}
.icon {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
}
.imageBlock {
  display: block !important;
  height: auto !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
img[Attributes Style] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

wher upper takes precedence over lower

lastly, i know it's not your code, but avoid as much as you can the !important, since when you really need them, they won't work.

Comment: I was wondering why there is two references to .icon. Also, they marked almost every rule as !important. Do you think it has anything to do with the fact this is email coding? Maybe they wanted the email client to render it properly? Thanks for the advice, though this helps. I have a feeling that while the end result of the whole file is nice, it has somewhat messy coding.